# Should I complete BehaviorSubject on the component destroy – Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, subject

I have a service provided in a component, so it runs `ngOnDestory` if the component is going to be destroyed. Every subscription runs with `takeUntil(this.destory$)` (which emits on the component's `ngOnDestory` hook) or with the `async` pipe, so everything is unsubscribed when the component destroys.

The question is, if I have a BehaviorSubject inside the service, should I run its `.complete()` and/or `.unsubscribe()` methods inside the service's `ngOnDestory` or I am good to go as it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should unsubscribe on `ngOnDestroy`; not necessarily complete the subject if it is inside the service, because other components might still be using the subject and still need it to work properly.

The services are singletons but their lifecycle depends on the injector in which they are provided. If your service is provided in the root injector, it lives as long as your application, so when you create the component that needs that subject again, you won't be able to reuse it without some sort of reinitialization.

You mentioned that you do have `takeUntil(this.destroy$)` which should not lead to a memory leak, but be sure to also call `complete` on `this.destroy$` inside your `ngOnDestroy`.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroy$.next();
  this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to add to this answer: a while ago I wrote an article which describes why memory leaks occur when using Subjects in RxJS. [Link here](https://indepth.dev/posts/1433/rxjs-why-memory-leaks-occur-when-using-a-subject).

Comment: It's clear that I should not compete a subject if it's provided in root. I'm asking should I do it if it is not a singleton?

Comment: You should not complete it, just make sure you don't have memory leaks. Based on the code you provided, you should be good without completing the subject in the service.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Do I correctly understood from your article that since the reason of memory leaks are obsolete subscriptions, if I unsubscribed from all subscribers, I do not need to complete the subject, since it will be correctly destroyed by itself, along with the component?

Comment: @RomanovEugene Yes, if, for instance, the subject is created within a component, then the component is the only thing that holds a reference to the subject. So, if the component is destroyed, the subject is no longer referenced at all, so it can be safely garbage collected. [Completing the subject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L83-L94) only activates a flag and sends a complete notification to all subject's subscribers.